# jQuery selector |= in $("[name|='value']")

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I found this snippet in some javascript code:

```
var name = "someString";
var s = "[name|='"+name+"']";
var nArr = $JQ(s);
```

Can someone explain what `|=` does?

I can see in my debug tool that I receive an array of jQuery elements, which all have `someString` in their name. But I wasn't able to find an explanation in the jQuery documentation. What am I missing?

Comment: From http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-prefix-selector/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is [attribute contains prefix selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-prefix-selector/)

> Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value either equal to a given string or starting with that string followed by a hyphen (-).

```js
$("a[hreflang|='en']").css("color", "green");
```

```css
a {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="example.html" hreflang="en">Some text</a>
<a href="example.html" hreflang="en-UK">Some other text</a>
<a href="example.html" hreflang="english">will not be selected</a>
```

---

This selector was introduced into the CSS specification to handle language attributes.

[**W3**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-selectors)

> Represents an element with the att attribute, its value either being exactly "val" or beginning with "val" immediately followed by "-" (U+002D). This is primarily intended to allow language subcode matches (e.g., the hreflang attribute on the a element in HTML) as described in BCP 47 ([BCP47]) or its successor.

Comment: Thank you for this comprehensive and fast answer. Just for my understanding: Should this prefix selector be used for language attributes only?

Comment: @Rattlesnake The main use case is for language attributes as language is defined as `en`, `en-us`, `en-uk`, etc. You can use this for your elements also if the values are in this format